# Объявление объекта класса

Tags: c++, классы

В классе `A` есть конструктор по умолчанию и конструктор с 1 параметром.

При таком `A x();` и таком `A x;` объявлениях объекта класса `A` выполняются разные действия. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A x();` - это объявление функции `x` которая возвращает результат с типом `A`.

В Си и С++ функции можно объявлять в т.ч. и внутри функций, например

```
int main() {
  int f(); // объявили функцию, которая будет определена ниже.
  return f();
}

int f() { return 0; }
```

Чтобы объявить переменную, используйте фигурные скобки:

```
A x{};
```

Или просто используйте `A x;`.

Answer (score 3):

Данная конструкция

```
A x();
```

является объявлением функции с именем `x`, которая возвращает объект класса `A` и не имеет параметров.

Данная конструкция

```
A x;
```

действительно является объявлением объекта класса `A` с именем `x` , для создания которого вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: @Abyx я объявлял так `A x();` и писал `cout << x`. Всё работало, `<<` в классе определена

Comment: В смысле не было ошибок компиляции, а выводило `1`

Comment: По идее должно возвращать объект типа A, а так как он не был создан, то конструктор по умолчанию вызовется. Нет?

Comment: @Abyx хе, прикольно, спасибо